# How to make delete button visible only when one or multiple checkboxes is/are selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
//not getting any response from this code
if ($('#DesignationTable input[class=Organization_Desg_Check_margin]:checked').length) {
  alert("check box is selected");
}
//code to select all check boxes
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="Main_Checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      var checkBoxes = $('.Organization_Desg_Check_margin');
      checkBoxes.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      var checkBoxes = $('.Organization_Desg_Check_margin');
      checkBoxes.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DesignationTable">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Main_Checkbox" id="check_all" class="mt-1 ml-1" />

  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row1" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row2" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData2" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row3" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData3" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row4" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData4" />
</div>
```

I have a table and each row consists of a checkbox, Only when any one or multiple checkboxes are checked the delete option need to displayed

[image]

Comment: first try something, then if you stuck then ask question with that tried code.

Comment: I fixed your snippet. PS: jquery() is not valid syntax

Comment: @DevsiOdedra OP has updated the question sufficiently

Comment: @mplungjan Undownvoted! Thanks for notifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate

change "delete" to whatever the ID is of your delete button

```js
$(function() {
  $("#DesignationTable").on("click", function() {
    $("#delete").toggle($(this).find(".Organization_Desg_Check_margin:checked").length > 0);
  })
  $('input[name="Main_Checkbox"]').on("click", function() {
    $('.Organization_Desg_Check_margin').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
 
});
```

```css
#delete { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DesignationTable">

  <button type="button" id="delete">Delete</button>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Main_Checkbox" id="check_all" class="mt-1 ml-1" />

  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row1" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row2" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData2" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row3" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData3" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Organization_Desg_row4" class="Organization_Desg_Check_margin" id="OrganizationDesgCheckData4" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what framework you use, the main logic would be something like creating an array to hold `checkedItems`. At your delete button, you can set it to visible only when `checkedItems.length > 0`.

As others have suggested, please try it yourself, share if there is anything that's not working from `your code`